# Linq to Objects - How many times will the query execute?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following Linq to Objects query:

```
var query = this._vaporizerData
    .Where(row => row.Coater == coater)
    .Where(row => row.Distributor == distributor)
    .Where(row => row.PowerTubeA.HasValue);

if (query.Any())
{
    tubeA = query
        .Where(row => row.CoaterTime.Value >= readTime.AddMinutes(-5))
        .Where(row => row.CoaterTime.Value <= readTime)
        .OrderByDescending(row => row.CoaterTime)
        .Select(row => row.PowerTubeA)
        .First()
        .Value;
}
```

I know that when the query.Any() line is executed, the first Linq query is evaluated. My question is this. Let's assume the results of the first query is 5 rows of data. When I execute the second query (starting with 'tubeA = query'), am I correct it will evaluate this against just the five rows returned from the first query?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I know that when the query.Any() line is executed, the first Linq query is evaluated.

Well, sort of. It's evaluated *as far as necessary*. So if you have a million rows in `_vaporizerData` but the first of them matches the filter, it's not going to iterate over the rest of the data.

> When I execute the second query (starting with 'tubeA = query'), am I correct it will evaluate this against just the five rows returned from the first query?

Yes, but it will have to find those rows again, checking the filter against all the rows which didn't match the first time. So again, if you have a million rows in `_vaporizerData` but this time only the *last* row matches the original query, you'll end up checking against all the 999,999 non-matching rows again.

Also, if anything else changes the contents of `_vaporizerData` between the call to `Any()` and the call to `First()`, those changes *will* be visible, as it really is going back to the original data source.

It would be better to only execute the query once, e.g.

```
var minTime = readTime.AddMinutes(-5); // Avoid recalculation
var result = this._vaporizerData
                 .Where(row => row.Coater == coater)
                 .Where(row => row.Distributor == distributor)
                 .Where(row => row.PowerTubeA.HasValue);
                 .Where(row => row.CoaterTime.Value >= minTime)
                 .Where(row => row.CoaterTime.Value <= readTime)
                 .OrderByDescending(row => row.CoaterTime)
                 .Select(row => row.PowerTubeA)
                 .FirstOrDefault();

if (result != null)
{
    tubeA = result.Value;
}
```

EDIT: Two important points noted in comments:

- Your original query would throw an exception if we the first query matched an item but the second didn't; the code above would just end up with `result` as null. That may or may not be an issue for you.
- If you use [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com) you could make this more efficient by using `.MaxBy(row => row.CoaterTime)` instead of using `OrderByDescending` and `First`. IIRC, that will fail on an empty input though, so you should only do this if you're using your original version with `First`, not the version above.

Comment: Thanks Jon. This is not what I want to happen, so it looks like I should convert the results of my first query to a List so I doesn't need to find those five rows a second time.

Comment: Also note that you could use `MinBy`, rather than an `OrderBy`/`First`.

Comment: To strictly replicate the query in the question, if result is null, we need to re-examine the original set, determine if the first set of predicates would be matched, and throw an exception if this is the case.

Comment: @JonHanna: That's true. Hopefully not an issue though :)

Answer (score 1):

Lets imagine the collection is a list. Lets imagine that whether they match the first three criteria is as:

```
F, T, F, F, F, T, F, F, F, T, F, F, T, F, T, F, F, F
```

(T = matches, F = Doesn't match)

The call to  `Any` will examine two elements. At that point it knows there is at least one item. It does not examine any more elements, but returns true.

Let's say those that also match the other predicates are as:

```
F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, T, F, T, F, F, F
```

Because we've an `OrderByDescending` it will have to examine every single item, to produce it's result. There's no other way to know which came first.

If it didn't, it would examine 13, consider it "first", and be done.

On the one hand, this general sort of case can be one where `ToList()` can make things faster - because we reuse query results, rather than just reusing queries, the benefit of storing the intermediate results can outweigh the cost of creating the list.

On the other, other re-uses of queries want exactly this sort of behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The second query does not use the results from the first query.
So you are hitting the object with two queries. 1 for the `.Any()` and 1 for the `.First()`

If you want to reuse the results from the first query without hitting the object a second time then use `ToList()` like this:

```
var query = this._vaporizerData
    .Where(row => row.Coater == coater)
    .Where(row => row.Distributor == distributor)
    .Where(row => row.PowerTubeA.HasValue).ToList();
```

This will store the first query results in the `query`, other wise `query` doesnt hold any values but is actually a statement to make a query.

Comment: What's your basis for assuming that `_vaporizerData` represents an IQueryable that will result in a database query?  For all we know it's just a `List`.

Comment: Regardless if it is a db or a list. It is still hitting the datasource `_vaporizerData` twice, which if you dont know it does that then it can degrade performance.

Comment: Check the title of the question - This is Linq to Objects.

Comment: @Servy in fact, the question specifies LinqToObjects, so we can be fairly sure that _vaporizerData is *not* IQueryable.

Comment: @phoog Yes, exactly, and yet this answer seems to indicate the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

If your base collection has many more objects than your query will return, you probably shouldn't call `Any`, because, as you suspect, it will most likely result in many of these objects being evaluated twice against the first set of criteria.  Instead, execute the first query once by calling `ToList` or `ToArray`:

```
var interimResults = this._vaporizerData 
    .Where(row => row.Coater == coater) 
    .Where(row => row.Distributor == distributor) 
    .Where(row => row.PowerTubeA.HasValue)
    .ToList(); 

if (interimResults.Count > 0) 
{ 
    tubeA = interimResults
        .Where(row => row.CoaterTime.Value >= readTime.AddMinutes(-5)) 
        .Where(row => row.CoaterTime.Value <= readTime) 
        .OrderByDescending(row => row.CoaterTime) 
        .Select(row => row.PowerTubeA) 
        .First() 
        .Value; 
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind he only needs the first result, and the intermediate query hasn't applied all of the filters.  You could potentially be copying lots and lots of data to a list only to throw out all but one of them.  Jon's answer avoid that problem.

Comment: @Servy that's true.  I suppose Jon's answer is better, but I am just a bit uncomfortable using the `...OrDefault` methods.